# nc: connectx to 10.167.71.255 port 9000 (tcp) failed: Permission denied

Tags: networking

I am trying to do some simple testing. I have the following simple program taken directly from https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html

```
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer
import sys

address = sys.argv[1]
port = int(sys.argv[2])
Handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer((address, port), Handler)

print "serving at port", port
httpd.serve_forever()
```

I run it as follows

```
$ python run-server.py 10.167.71.255 9000
serving at port 9000
```

but when I try to test the connection using `nc` on the same host I get below error:

```
$ nc -zv 10.167.71.255 9000
nc: connectx to 10.167.71.255 port 9000 (tcp) failed: Permission denied
```

also see below:

```
$ ping 10.167.71.255
PING 10.167.71.255 (10.167.71.255): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.167.64.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=10.039 ms
64 bytes from 10.167.71.230: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=17.371 ms
64 bytes from 10.167.64.54: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=20.518 ms
64 bytes from 10.167.66.7: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=53.512 ms
64 bytes from 10.167.64.61: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=63.255 ms
64 bytes from 10.167.70.222: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=79.729 ms
64 bytes from 10.167.71.226: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=82.209 ms
64 bytes from 10.167.64.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=9.517 ms
64 bytes from 10.167.71.230: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=51.154 ms
64 bytes from 10.167.64.54: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=63.806 ms
64 bytes from 10.167.66.7: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=69.370 ms
64 bytes from 10.167.64.61: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=76.288 ms
64 bytes from 10.167.70.222: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=92.728 ms
64 bytes from 10.167.71.226: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=95.862 ms
64 bytes from 10.167.64.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=12.934 ms
64 bytes from 10.167.71.230: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=12.963 ms
64 bytes from 10.167.66.7: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=92.860 ms
64 bytes from 10.167.64.61: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=96.639 ms
64 bytes from 10.167.64.54: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=109.596 ms
64 bytes from 10.167.70.222: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=115.139 ms
64 bytes from 10.167.71.226: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=117.198 ms
64 bytes from 10.167.64.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=10.212 ms
64 bytes from 10.167.66.7: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=11.361 ms
64 bytes from 10.167.70.222: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=12.489 ms
64 bytes from 10.167.71.229: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=1015.966 ms
64 bytes from 10.167.71.229: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=12.709 ms
^C
--- 10.167.71.255 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 packets received, +22 duplicates, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 9.517/92.516/1015.966/188.465 ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was that `10.167.71.255` was the broadcast address not the IP address. But  the server did not throw any error listening to broadcast address.